# Type casting difference

Tags: c++, casting

Hi I would like to know what is the difference between these two forms of type casting:

```
float flt=2.33;
int x;
x=static_cast<int> flt;
```

and

```
  x=(int)flt;
```

Answer (score 0):

The static_cast is a C++ style cast whereas the () cast inherits from C. Try to use static_cast over the C cast as it is more reliable in terms of providing compile time errors in your cast instead of just letting the compiler ignore fatal bugs.